# Flutter: Remove brightness bar from flutter_colorpicker

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I used the [flutter_colorpicker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_colorpicker) package to implement a color picker in my app. My `widget` looks something like this:

```dart
ColorPicker(
  pickerColor: ...,
  paletteType: PaletteType.hueWheel,
  onColorChanged: (color) {
    ...
  },
  enableAlpha: false,
  labelTypes: const [],
)
```

In the UI it looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to remove the brightness bar on the bottom. I know that the color picker is not complete without that brighness bar but I will handle the brightness a different way. I have found no official documentation on how to achieve this.

How do I remove that bar? Hacks are also welcome or somehow extending the package with inheritance.

Comment: Is your requirement is compulsory use for this package?

Comment: I would highly appreciate it if I can stick to his package yes.

Comment: Got it. But in some packages we can't remove some by default part of those packages. My suggestion to you is either you can open issue related this package on Github or you can use other color packages as well.

Comment: Yeah I should probably open an issue for this but I am positive there must be a way to "hack" it in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by clipping away that bar using a `ClipRect` widget:

```dart
ClipRect(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        heightFactor: 0.75,
        child: ColorPicker(
          ...
          colorPickerWidth: 250,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I have not found any unwanted side effects with this approach yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here I attach some links which contains no brightnesss bar

[Flutter Material Color Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_material_color_picker)

[Flex Color Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/flex_color_picker)